# How to convert string to string[]?

Tags: c#

How to convert `string` type to `string[]` type in C#?

Comment: arguments to methods is the only context I can think of. String.Split comes to mind (myString.Split(`new[]{", "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` for example)

Comment: @Mihir add why and how do you want to do this. Do you want split a string? "hi there Mihir" -> string.split(' ') ["hi", "there", "Mihir"].

Answer (score 154, accepted):

`string[]` is an array (vector) of strings
`string` is just a string (a list/array of characters)

Depending on how you want to convert this, the canonical answer could be:

### string[] -> string

```
return String.Join(" ", myStringArray);
```

### string -> string[]

```
return new []{ myString };
```

Answer (score 37):

An array is a fixed collection of same-type data that are stored contiguously and that are accessible by an index (zero based).

A string is a sequence of characters.

Hence a `String[]` is a collection  of `Strings`.

For example:

```
String foo = "Foo";  // one instance of String
String[] foos = new String[] { "Foo1", "Foo2", "Foo3" };
String firstFoo = foos[0];  // "Foo1"
```

[Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

**Edit**: So obviously there's no direct way to convert a single `String` to an `String[]`
or vice-versa. Though you can use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) to get a `String[]` from a `String` by using a separator(for example comma).

To "convert" a `String[]` to a `String`(the opposite) you can use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx). You need to specify how you want to join those strings(f.e. with comma).

Here's an example:

```
var foos = "Foo1,Foo2,Foo3";
var fooArray = foos.Split(',');  // now you have an array of 3 strings
foos = String.Join(",", fooArray); // now you have the same as in the first line
```

Answer (score 26):

If you want to convert a string like `"Mohammad"` to `String[]` that contains all characters as `String`, this may help you:

```
"Mohammad".ToCharArray().Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray()
```

Comment: this is what he searched for probably. One of the uses is for example in a FrameWork that accepts no 'SendKeys' but the pure raising keyboard event purely. This even only takes one byte per raise

Answer (score 17):

You can create a `string[]` (string array) that contains your `string` like :

```
string someString = "something";
string[] stringArray = new string[]{ someString };
```

The variable `stringArray` will now have a length of 1 and contain `someString`.

Comment: I don't think this is the intended result.

Answer (score 13):

To convert a string with comma separated values to a string array use `Split`:

```
string strOne = "One,Two,Three,Four";
string[] strArrayOne = new string[] {""};
//somewhere in your code
strArrayOne = strOne.Split(',');
```

Result will be a string array with four strings:

> {"One","Two","Three","Four"}

Comment: String strOne = "One,Two,Three,Four";
String[] strArrayOne = new String[] {""};
//somewhere in your code
strArrayOne = strOne.split(",");

Answer (score 5):

zerkms told you the difference. If you like you can "convert" a string to an array of strings with length of 1.

If you want to send the string as a argument for example you can do like this:

```
var myString = "Test";

MethodThatRequiresStringArrayAsParameter( new[]{myString} );
```

I honestly can't see any other reason of doing the conversion than to satisty a method argument, but if it's another reason you will have to provide some information as to what you are trying to accomplish since there is probably a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

`string` is a string, and `string[]` is an array of strings

Comment: @Zerkms.. I am not only asking the difference. I asked how to convert from one to another form?

Comment: @Mihir To be fair to zerkms, you titled your question "Difference between....". The title has since been edited to match your actual question.

Answer (score 3):

A `string` is one string, a `string[]` is a string array. It means it's a variable with multiple strings in it.

Although you can convert a `string` to a `string[]` (create a string array with one element in it), it's probably a sign that you're trying to do something which you shouldn't do.

Answer (score 3):

Casting can also help converting string to string[]. In this case, casting the string with ToArray() is demonstrated:

```
String myString = "My String";
String[] myString.Cast<char>().Cast<string>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

A string holds one value, but a string[] holds many strings, as it's an array of string.

See more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3hd7ste.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are just a beginner and want to split a string into an array of letters but didn't know the right terminology for that is a char[];

```
String myString = "My String";
char[] characters = myString.ToCharArray();
```

If this is not what you were looking for, sorry for wasting your time :P