# How Do I Split a String Into a string[]?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq

I have a string:

```
string strToBeSplitted = "HelloWorld";
```

And I am planning to split my string to an array of string. Usually we do it with char:

```
char[] charReturn = strToBeSplitted.ToCharArray();
```

But what I am planning to do is return it with an array of string like this one:

```
string[] strReturn = strToBeSplitted ???
//Which contains strReturn[0] = "H"; and so on...
```

I want to return an array of string but I cannot figure out how to do this unless I do this manually by converting it to char then to a new string like StringBuilder.

Comment: You can refer following answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081549/how-to-convert-string-to-string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `.Select` which will iterate through each characters in the given string, and `.ToString()` will help you to convert a character to a string, and finally `.ToArray()` can help you to store the `IEnumerable<string>` into a string array. Hope that this is what you are looking for:

```
string strToBeSplitted = "HelloWorld";
string[] strArray = strToBeSplitted.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this will do the job :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq to quickly transform it:

```
strToBeSplitted.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: `ToCharArray` is not necessary, you can directly apply `Select`, See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, `RegEx` approach to split between characters:

```
string[] charReturn = Regex.Split("HelloWorld", "(?!^)(?<!$)");
```